# How to put Syntax Highlighted codes in TextArea

Tags: html, syntax-highlighting

I hava created a simple syntax highlighter using Rainbow and it is working good now I want to put my result codes in a textarea but whenever I am doing this,

```
var text='<pre><code data-language="java">'+MyCode+'</code></pre>';
document.write(text);
```

it is not working. Actually I want to make something like this: [this](http://tohtml.com) where output text with all color codes are printing in textarea.

Comment: what exactly happens? the code is not highlighted or there is no code shown at all?

Comment: `textarea` does not support multiple different formats (colors, font styles,...) for different parts of its content. You'll need to find or make a custom editor using JavaScript.

Answer (score 1):

**edit:**
http://codemirror.net/ seems to do just this.

as far as i know, you can not highlight / stylize parts of a textarea. it's either the whole textarea or no style.

you can check out http://www.jsfiddle.net to see how they did it. It's complicated.